# loading data from ajax into html label and listbox not working

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am making an ajax to call data from database with php and i want to load the result in two inputs(label and listbox) in html page,the problem is that it show the value in the label`#FrmCount` but it is not showing anything in the listbox `#FarmersID`..
Here is the ajax

```
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"AddData.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:
        { 
            'Order_ID': Order_ID, 
            'Frm_ID':Frm_ID,
            'Frm_Wet':Frm_Wet,
            'Frm_Dry':Frm_Dry,
            'Frm_Fermented':Frm_Fermented,
            'Frm_Date':Frm_Date
        },
    success: function(data)
        {   
            $("#FrmCount").html(data.FarmerCount);
            $("#FarmersID").html(data.FarmersID);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('ERROR', textStatus, errorThrown);
    }

})
```

And this is the php code:

```
$stmt1 ="SELECT distinct Farm_id FROM ordersfarmers WHERE Order_ID='".$_POST["Order_ID"]."'AND Reply='1'";

        $results=$conn->query($stmt1)->fetchAll();
        $res=count($results);
        foreach ($conn->query($stmt1) as $row) 
        {
            $json = array("FarmerCount" => $res,
          "FarmersID" => $row['Farm_id']
          );
        echo json_encode($json);
        }
```

and the html part

```
<div>
<select name="FarmersID" id="FarmersID" multiple style="width:280px;height:110px;" onclick="showonmap()">   
</select>
</div>
<div>
<label id="FrmCount"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump ($_POST)?

Comment: @IgorUnger i don't know how to use it..can you tell me?

Comment: Just type: var_dump($_POST); before your $stmt1. Then you will see if your server is receiving your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With code `$("#FarmersID").html(data.FarmersID);` you basiclly creating something like:

```
<select name="FarmersID" id="FarmersID" multiple style="width:280px;height:110px;" onclick="showonmap()">
1 <!-- your id -->
</style>
```

That's not a proper select format, what you need is create `option` inside html. For this example you can do:

```
$("#FarmersID").append('<option value="' + data.FarmerID + '">' + data.FarmerID + '</option>');
```

But you will always end up with one element. You should return an array (you are not doing that at the moment) or you can build proper html in your `php` and return that to your `javascrip`.

Edit:

```
foreach ($conn->query($stmt1) as $row) 
{
    $farmesIds[$row['Farm_id']] = $row['Farm_id'];
}
$json = array(
    "FarmerCount" => $res,
    "FarmersID" => $farmesIds
);
echo json_encode($json);
```

And in javascript

```
$.each(data.FarmersID, function(id, value) {
    $("#FarmersID").append('<option value="' + id + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
```

You can pass something else as value (label or smth?) and keep ID as a key.

Comment: Thanks..it works :)...but the result is more than one element...can you tell me how to make it?

Comment: See my edit above. BTW, I hope you know that you should never build query as you doing in your example, with $_POST param.

Comment: I changed `$_POST` param to a variable one `$OrID`

Comment: You should use bindParams for every query.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is not correct.

You are fetching all the results, and then you try to fetch again, but the statement pointer is already at the end of the dataset.

Try this :

```
$results = $conn->query($stmt1)->fetchAll();
$res = count($results);

$json = array(
    "FarmerCount" => $res,
    "FarmersID" => $results
);
echo json_encode($json);
```

And you don't need this `FarmerCount` item in your array, you can just get this number by doing `data.FarmersID.length`.